# What options do I have to charge my GPS and Phone using a dynamo hub?

Tags: touring, gps, dynamo, iphone

I'm planning to purchase a supernova infinity-8 dynamo hub and wanted to use this during daylight hours to charge my Phone and GPS during bike tours.

What products are available that will work with hub dynamos to charge iphone and Garmin GPS units?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-can-i-charge-my-phone-while-cycling

Comment: I can't help but suggest you to consider Schmidt (SON) hubs. I own one and the thing is very nice. Got a problem and the company replaced it "almost" for free...

Comment: I'm a fan if the supernova hub due to the ability to disable the dynamo and coast with no resistance when I don't need to power any devices or lights.

Comment: I know this is offtopic from your question, but does an unloaded dynamo hub have significant drag? If you have a Schmidt hub, and spin the wheel, how quickly does it come to a stop?

Comment: Relevant link: http://cyclingabout.com/index.php/2012/03/list-of-hub-dynamo-power-supplies-for-usb-devices/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option:

http://h1987995.stratoserver.net/magento/supernova-the-plug-ii-plus-usb-dynamolader.html

SUPERNOVA The Plug II Plus USB power supply

- Transforms dynamo AC to exact USB spec. DC 5V, 500 mA
- E‐Bike compatible for 12‐ 48V DC with optional cable
- Works with Garmin, Ipod&Iphone 3GS & 4G & 4GS

Seems pretty expensive at €159, but since it's from SuperNova, it should work perfectly with your hub. It's only rated at 500mA, so it'll only do "slow charging" of your phone - most smart phones these days use a 1000mA (or higher) fast charger.

For those in the USA, here's a domestic source:

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6V22K44405&cm_re=SUPERNOVA_dynamo-*-9SIA6V22K44405-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6V22K44405&cm_re=SUPERNOVA_dynamo-_-9SIA6V22K44405-_-Product)

$156 + shipping. Still seems expensive given that they sell the hub itself for only $216.

Comment: Like you said, good but expensive. Anyway, I almost killed my gps by trying to feed it with my dynamo using a home-made circuit. So, if that stuff works "fuss free", might well be worth it (specially if it's waterproof). Also, batteries are definitely NOT free or everlasting, and things will end up paying up themselves...

Comment: I presume this is a Supernova-branded version of the Tout-Terrain original. If so it seems to be generally regarded as the best option, there's a helpful comparison of your options here: http://www.cyclingabout.com/list-of-hub-dynamo-power-supplies-for-usb-devices/

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at the [Biologic ReeCharge](https://www.thinkbiologic.com/products/reecharge-dynamo-kit-micro-usb-cable) by [Dahon](https://www.dahon.com/). It says it hooks up to any standard dynamo hub. The nice thing about this is that it has its own battery. So the dynamo charges the internal battery and the battery charges your phone/gps/device. This allows you to charge while you are resting, as well as provide added protection against sending bad current to your device.  I don't have any experience with it, but the idea is sound, and Dahon has many good products. It sells for $100 which isn't too bad considering it has its own battery.

Answer (score 2):

I have been. Using the Biologic Reecharge for 4 years...It charges my Samung Galaxy Express with no problem....It works best if you start with the battery on the unit charged AND the battery on your phone charged...then just leave it on while ridng and it will actually. OVERCHARGE.....so let the phone drop to 80% and then start the charging...it will charge back up and turn it off and do it again and again and it will stay charged indefinitely!!